Should a larger lamp cord wire connect to the larger blade of a polarized plug?
The wires of an old lamp burned off inside the non-polarized plug. I have a new polarized plug. One of the two copper wires on the old lamp cord appears to be slightly larger than the other. Is it correct to assume that the apparently larger wire should go on the larger prong?

Welcome. Please take the [tour].

It would be interesting to see a picture of this cord showing different wire sizes. Especially if it could also show the end where the bare wires are, too, so we can see if it's the wires or the sheaths are different sizes or both. I've never seen two-conductor lamp cord with different wire sizes.

No. The larger prong is the neutral conductor. It's larger so it can't be inserted into the hot slot on an outlet. I'd expect the larger diameter wire to be for the hot side.
That said, it's strange in the first place that a non-polarized cord would have disparate wire sizes. It could be simply a case of the insulation being larger, or shaped differently to indicate polarity.
You need to trace the circuit and make sure that the wire for the smaller prong goes to the center contact in the bulb socket, not the outer threaded housing. Energizing that would be a safety concern, and some devices, such as outlet adapters, would end up with with reverse polarity.

The insulation might have stretched when over heating.

Unless there is a short from hot to ground (breaker trip, so no...) or neutral to ground, there is no way a bulb should "know" the difference between correct and reverse polarity. (1/3 of my house would not have worked (before I fixed the numerous reverses if that were the case.)

LED and some other fancier bulbs may well "know" which wire is hot and which not.

@kreemoweet Not true. Without referencing ground, there is no way to tell hot from neutral on a household AC circuit.

I discovered that the wire casing (insulation) had a ridge on one side. The ridged side was connect to the bulb center (hence the "identified" hot wire.) The wire in the smooth side of the casing was connected to the outside of the bulb socket (hence the neutral wire) and therefore needed to be connected to the larger blade of the plug. Thanks!

Its possible the flex-cord is not original either.   Potentially, "old" lamp covers a lot of time.

I also agree that a bulb with only two connections, power and neutral, would not be able to tell whether power and neutral are reversed. Without a ground for a reference point, the bulb could only use the voltage to tell. And the voltage reverses 50-60 times a second. It would need a third connection to ground to identify which input wiggles and which input stays at ground to identify whether power and neutral were reversed.

Fair enough. My greater point was that some of the zillion things you can put in a bulb socket won't like it.
